# Startup displaying a modal window followed by a standard window

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am launching an MVVM application with code in the App.xaml.cs like so:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);

    //Set data directory
    string baseDir = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) + @"\BlowTrial";
    if (!Directory.Exists(baseDir))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(baseDir);
    }
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", baseDir);

    //Application initialisation
    AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure();

    //Security
    CustomPrincipal customPrincipal = new CustomPrincipal();
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetThreadPrincipal(customPrincipal);

    // Create the ViewModel to which 
    // the main window binds.
    var mainWindowVm = new MainWindowViewModel();
    MainWindow window = new MainWindow(mainWindowVm);

    // When the ViewModel asks to be closed, 
    // close the window.
    EventHandler handler = null;
    handler = delegate
    {
        window.Close();
        if (!window.IsLoaded) //in case user cancelled close event
        {
            mainWindowVm.RequestClose -= handler;
        }
    };
    mainWindowVm.RequestClose += handler;

    window.Show();
}
```

I would like to test for the existence of entities containing important data for running the application, and if these do not exist, run a wizard (as a dialog) which obtains these settings:

```
if (BlowTrialDataService.GetBackupDetails().BackupData == null
           || !_repository.LocalStudyCentres.Any())
{
      DisplayAppSettingsWizard();
}

static void DisplayAppSettingsWizard()
{
    //testfor and display starup wizard
    var wizard = new GetAppSettingsWizard();
    GetAppSettingsViewModel appSettings = new GetAppSettingsViewModel();
    wizard.DataContext = appSettings;
    EventHandler wizardHandler = null;
    wizardHandler = delegate
    {
        wizard.Close();
        wizard = null;
        appSettings.RequestClose -= wizardHandler;
    };
    appSettings.RequestClose += wizardHandler;
    wizard.ShowDialog();
}
```

When I place this code in the MainWindow.xaml.cs, the application runs correctly. When it is placed in either the App.xaml.cs (before the code to instantiate the instance of MainWindow), or in the constructor for MainWindowViewModel, the wizard displays correctly, but the application ends without displaying the MainWindow on completion of the wizard. If there is no cause to display the wizard, MainWindow displays correctly in all cases.

Examining the debug output, there are no errors of note (a few first chance exceptions related to sql commands).

Is there a reason for this - having the code in the code behind MainWindow.xaml does not seem the most logical place (which to my mind would be the app.xaml.cs).

Thank you for your expertise.

Comment: Feel free to comment on the downvote - that way I can improve future questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value of *ShutdownMode* is System.Windows.ShutdownMode.OnLastWindowClose which means if the last window was closed App will shutdown.
You didn't put all in code in here, I suppose that setting wizard window didn't show before main window closed, this lead app exit.
I suggest you set shutdownmode to OnExplicitShutdown which you can decide when to close your app by your own.

Comment: Thank you - that was the problem - I was not aware of this default